# AWS Site-to-Site VPN connections and subnet IP ranges

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking

Scenario:

- Site to site VPN connection between our AWS environment and a customer on-prem environment
- One EC2 instance in our environment is calling an API via VPN at customer on-prem

Question:

What IP range will the customer see the requests coming from? My assumption is, that the customer needs to setup a route from our internal private subnet range to it's subnet hosting the API component.

Hence, the traffic from customers point of view will come from our private sub net range.

Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Subnet is a single word. There is no hyphen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct. When the EC2 instance in your AWS environment sends a request to the API hosted in the customer's on-prem environment via the VPN connection, the source IP address of the request will be the private IP address assigned to the network interface of the EC2 instance in your AWS environment.

The customer will see the requests coming from your private subnet range, which you should have specified when configuring the VPN connection between the two environments. Therefore, the customer will need to set up a route from their on-prem network to route traffic destined for your private subnet range through the VPN connection.